# upload multi column versions using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I developed using rails4 and upload image file using carrierwave.

and I add column to myModel to upload another image column

```
class MyModel  < ActiveRecord::Base

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    ANDROID = {:image => [800, 355]}
    IPHONE = {:image => [800, 355]}
    THUMBNAIL = {:image => [150, 150]}

    mount_uploader :square_image, ImageUploader
    ANDROID = {:square_image => [800, 800]}
    IPHONE = {:square_image => [800, 800]}
    THUMBNAIL = {:square_image => [150, 150]}
end
```

after modified file's

my rails project make warning message

```
 warning: already initialized constant MyModel::ANDROID
 DEBUG[c0668d68]    app/models/my_model.rb:LINE_NUMBER: warning: previous definition of ANDROID was here
```

I don't know how i doing..

Help me ~.

Comment: you are defining same constants for different images so you are getting warning like that please ensure the constants you are using are different for different images

Comment: @anusha is it not accept using same constants? if it possible, can you explain how do i ?

Comment: Yes because we cannot set constants more than once so define another 3 different constants for square_image field like `ANDROID_SQUARE = {:square_image => [800, 800]}
    IPHONE_SQUARE = {:square_image => [800, 800]}
    THUMBNAIL_SQUARE = {:square_image => [150, 150]}` use these variables whereever you are using for square image and ofr normal image use the constants which you have defined earlier

Comment: @anusha OK@!!! Thx to advice~ :)